# Linear Movement between 2 objects

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a small game project and I have come into problem trying to move object from point A to point B with a solid movement speed and a linear movement path.

With my research I have found a piece of code to do this, but it doesn't seem to work perfectly as the speed seems to be different depending on the angle it is moving to.

This is the code at the moment:

```
Dim x As Single, y As Single
Dim sngInc As Single
Dim lStepValue As Long

Dim PT1X = pObj.Left
Dim PT1Y = pObj.Top
Dim PT2X = pTarget.Left
Dim PT2Y = pTarget.Top
If PT1Y = PT2Y Then
    sngInc = 1
    If PT2X > PT1X Then
        lStepValue = 1
    Else
        lStepValue = -1
    End If
    y = PT1Y
    x = PT1X
    x += lStepValue * sngInc
    pObj.Left = x
    pObj.Top = y
Else
    If PT2Y > PT1Y Then
        lStepValue = 1
    Else
        lStepValue = -1
    End If
    sngInc = (PT2X - PT1X) / Math.Abs(PT1Y - PT2Y)

    x = PT1X
    y = PT1Y
    y += lStepValue
    x = x + sngInc * Math.Abs(lStepValue)
    pObj.Left = x
    pObj.Top = y
End If
```

At my test project, it's under a timer with a tick of 30ms. I translated it from a VB6 code I found somewhere. The problem is as I stated above, is that the movement speed will not be exactly value of 1, but something near to it
depending on the angle.

I only found solutions using VB6 code I found and I have no experience on this subject. I am not even sure if it is called linear movement between 2 object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a variant of the digital differential analyzer, which is used to rasterize a line. But that's not what you want. Here is an alternative:

Given a source point `(PT1X, PT1Y)` and a target point `(PT2X, PT2Y)`, you first need to initialize the movement direction. It seems that you're not familiar with vector maths, so I try to explain it on a low level. But I suggest you look into vector arithmetics sooner or later. It makes life much easier.

The movement direction is simply the difference of the two points:

```
Dim dirX As Single = PT2X - PT1X
Dim dirY As Single = PT2Y - PT1Y
```

We can calculate the length of this direction (distance of the two points) with Pythagora's theorem:

```
Dim l = Math.Sqrt(dirX * dirX + dirY * dirY)
```

If we divide the direction components by this length, we get a direction that points towards the target and has a length of 1. I.e. if we add this direction to a point, the point moves exactly one unit in the direction of the target. But we probably want to specify a certain velocity `v`. Hence, we multiply by that:

```
dirX = dirX * v / l
dirY = dirY * v / l
```

All the above steps can be executed before any movement. Now, the update in each frame is simply:

```
pObj.Left += dirX
pObj.Top += dirY
```